# Merb & DataMapper - accessing database connection info?

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper, merb

I'm using Merb and DataMapper with a MySQL db. I want to access the database name, user, and password from a Rake task for my Merb app. I guess I could `YAML.load()` the the database.yml, but that seems ugly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
desc "outputs database connection parameters"
task :db_conn => :merb_env do |t|
  puts "Username: #{DataMapper.repository.adapter.uri.user}"
  puts "Password: #{DataMapper.repository.adapter.uri.password}"
  puts "Database: #{DataMapper.repository.adapter.uri.path.split('/').last}"
end
```

The interesting part there is the `=> :merb_env` bit. That ensures that the "merb_env" task has executed before your task does.  This simply loads up the Merb environment, at which point you can proceed to inspect its configuration.